# Uniformly continuous on subsets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f\colon S\to\Bbb R$ be uniformly continuous. Let $A\subset S$. Show that the restriction $f\mid _A$ is uniformly
continuous.

I have the following:

There exists an $\alpha > 0$ such that 
$(a-\alpha,a+\alpha)/\{a\}$ intersected with $A=(a-\alpha,a+\alpha)/\{a\}$ intersected with S. 
 Since f[a is within f, all points in f[a are in f this if f is uniformly continuous then f[a is as well.
Is this enough, if not I am not sure which direction to take.

Comment: A=(a,b), S=[a,b]

Comment: It's not at all clear what your "intersected" line is all about, and not just because there's no $\LaTeX$. In particular, your reasoning there doesn't mention $f$. What does "$f[a$" mean? What does it mean for it to be "within $f$"?

Comment: f[a is the restriction of A within f

Comment: Not set-theory, so I removed the tag.

Comment: @Ink Does it matter? As long as uniform continuity makes sense for functions from $S$ to $\mathbb R$, any restriction of a uniformly continuous function ought to be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Of course you're right.

Comment: @Sharkos: My best guess as to the meaning of the "intersected" line is that there is an $\alpha>0$ such that the punctured interval $(a-\alpha,a+\alpha)\setminus\{a\}$ has the same intersection with $A$ as with $S$.  Unfortunately, that's not true in general; fortunately, it seems to have nothing to do with the problem.  I conclude that either my best guess is not good enough or the OP is very confused.

Comment: You can write $\setminus$ as `$\setminus$` and $\cap$ as `$\cap$`. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).